# select data from database without refreshing the page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

[image]While getting data from the database it is alerting `0000:00:00` while in the database it is inserting write date

```
<?php
  $query = "select * from Reply t1 inner join users t2 on t1.UserId = t2.UserId where comment = '$commentid'";
  $run1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
  $numberRows = mysqli_num_rows($run1);
  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($run1))
  {
    $Reply = $row1['Reply'];
    $UserId = $row1['UserId'];
    $UserName = $row1['UserName'];

    $date1 = $row['Date'];
    echo "<script>alert('$date1')</script>";

    $ageDate1 = time_elapsed_string($date1);
    echo "<script>alert('$ageDate1')</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Can you please put a code of `time_elapsed_string` function here?

Comment: 1/ Can you show us an example of what you get in your database? 2/ What is the output of your select? 3/ What `time_elapsed_string()` do?

Comment: @MickaelLeger I have updated and alert is showing 0000:00:00

Comment: @RaviManiyar is working right as I am using it in another section also

Comment: @OwaisLatif Ok so you edit my first point, can you show us what `var_dump($row1)` output in your while list too please? And the code for `time_elapsed_string()` too to understand if it can bug in some case :)

Comment: Yes, we would need to know what `time_elapsed_string()` is doing.